# Error al realizar un modelo lineal generalizado mixto a partir de una matrix hessian

Tags: r, glmm

Estoy intentando realizar un modelo lineal generalizado mixto a partir de una matriz Hessian, mediante R.

El input con el que parto está disponible en este link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XM1A6gSL-OD5MwmnKxZd-q2YXeEEg4tw/view?usp=sharing

El input contiene una tabla donde muestra los valores de concentración (columna Conc) y absorbancia (columnas A1 y A2) obtenidos a partir de los diferentes tipos de kits y métodos de extracción (columnas Kit1, kit2, kit3,metodo_I,metodo_II,metodo_III) de las diferentes especies (columna Especie).

Dependiendo de con que tipo de kit o que método se extraiga aparece un 1 donde se haya utilizando o la casilla vacía donde no se ha usado).

Una vez establecido el kit hago el modelo en R:

#cargo librerias

```
       library(glmmTMB)
       library(readxl)

       Input_2 <- read_excel("C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Doctorado/Escritura tesis/Resultados/Scripts/Ensayo_extracción/Input_2 - modified.xlsx")


   #el modelo asume que la especie es un factor aleatorio y la variable respuesta es conc, aunque más adelante haré para A1 y A2. Los factores fijos son Conc y Metodo.

       cmod_lme <- lme(Conc ~ Metodo + Kit,
            data=Input_2, 
            random =  ~ 1|Especie,method = 'REML')

       cmod_lme <- glmmTMB(Conc ~ Metodo_I * Kit_I + (1|Especie),data=Input_2)

       fixef(cmod_lme)$cond
```

Al obtener los valores de covarianza estos son iguales para Metodo_I, Kit_I  y su interacción

```
          (Intercept)       Metodo_I          Kit_I Metodo_I:Kit_I 
                53.01586       53.01586       53.01586       53.01586
```

¿Estoy haciéndolo bien? Es el input correcto para este análisis.

Agradezco cualquier aportación.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Algunas dudas: 1. ¿Qué librerías estás usando? 2. ¿Cuál es el modelo que genera el problema? ¿El `lme` o el `glmmTMB`? Un comentario: en principio donde no hay datos en las columnas Método_ y Kit_ no debería ser `NA` sino 0. De lo contrario lo más probable es que la función que ajusta el modelo elimine  directamente a esas filas.

Comment: la libreria es glmmTMB, ya he añadido dicha información a la pregunta. El modelo es comparar el método I con el kit I, o el método II con el kit I o la interacción de todos, es decir hacer todas las combinaciones necesarias. El problema de poner un 0 es que quizás toma los valores que pone 0 en el kit I y claro, si es cero no se corresponde a resultados obtenidos con el kit I, es por esto por lo que puse NA. Necesito aclarar este tipo de problemas

Comment: Entiendo que las variables Metodo_1:3 y Kit_1:3 son variables categóricas con categorías mutuamente excluyentes. El Método será uno de 1, 2 o 3 y el Kit será uno de 1, 2 o 3. En ese caso la práctica usual es usarla en el modelo como variable indicadora o dummy: se toman las categorías de esa variable y se hace una columna con cada categoría y se pone 1 para las filas en las que corresponde a esa categoría y 0 cuando no corresponde.  Está bien que el valor sea 0, el truco es que cuando se estima y se multiplica el coeficiente por es el valor de x. Como x= 0 contribuye 0 en la estimación de y.

Comment: En cambio para la categoría que es 1 se multiplica por 1 y sí contribuye al valor estimado de y. Eso generalmente se hace de manera automática cuando usamos una fórmula que incluye una factor: R convierte a ese factor en varias columnas en la matriz de predictores. En ese caso la primer categoría (o nivel o level) del factor se mueve implícitamente a la ordenada al origen. Por lo que veo en tus datos no es así.

Comment: Sugerencias: prueba pasar todos los NA de tu df a 0. `Input_2[is.na(Input_2)] <- 0` es una forma muy directa. Lo probé y desaparece el warning de non-positive-definite  hessian matrix y los coeficientes varían. No sé si esos resultados son razonables para lo que buscas. Alternativamente podrías tomar cada grupo de variables (Metodo y Kit) y crear factores y dejar que `glmmTMB` se encargue de crear la matriz de predictores. PD: lamento si no soy claro, es un tema muy complicado para explicarlo en 500 caracteres.

Comment: Gracias @mpaladino por tus respuesta, entiendo que si pongo un 0 y 1 el modelo toma los valores de 0 como 0 y los valores de 1 como 1 usandolo solo los que tienen 1 para el resultados final. Mi motivación con este análisis es saber que efecto tiene el kit 1,2,3 y método 1,2,3 en el valor de concetración por eso el factor no se mueve implícitamente en la ordenada al origen porque necesito ese valor.Si quieres podemos utilizar el chat para hablar de este tema ya que no entiendo correcamente la alternativa que me has dado. Muchas gracias de todas maneras

Comment: Cuando ejecuto para analizar la interacción de todos los factores (cmod_lme <- glmmTMB(Conc ~ Metodo_I * Metodo_II *Metodo_III * Kit_I * Kit_II * Kit_III + (1|Especie),data=Input_2)) obtengo este warning: Warning message:
In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :   Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119163/discussion-between-mpaladino-and-adrian-p-l).